transaction not allowed
i always get this error
Error Message: Not allowed
Opcode: [REVERT]
in
0x784520057e2bb7ceb6480fd69a1483e0d3a6a57a
https://www.tdly.co/tx/8453/0x100b7aed19cac29620631b926161845199e8940f47149a8507075a1cd6b5b8e1

From the transaction trace the token SPORE calls an unverified contract to "log" something, 0x784520057e2bb7ceb6480fd69a1483e0d3a6a57a. It has enough gas to continue but that contract reverts. Without source is hard to state something, but it looks like scam contracts: revert without a reason, calling unverified contracts, act innocent but revert with "log".
